# Why does this CALayer not display an image?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-animation

Can you guys tell why this code shows no image?

```
CALayer *layerBack = [CALayer layer];

addedObject = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%d", PREFIX, number] ofType:@"png"]];

layerBack.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,selectedImage.size.height,selectedImage.size.width);
layerBack.position=CGPointMake(200,200);

layerBack.contents = (id)selectedImage.CGImage;
// in theory I think this line should be equal to selectedImage.CGImage, but when I do that, Xcode shows me an error!

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layerBack];

[layerBack display];
```

This Quartz stuff is driving me crazy! Please help!

Yes, the image is there and is working, but all I see after this code is a blank screen.

Comment: Why don't you just use views, especially UIIMageView and it's imageNamed method which reduces this code to about three lines?

Comment: because I have to have the final result transferred to a file at the end and it is harder to copy the transformations from the UIViews to CGLayers at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this code is from your view controller and that its view has been properly constructed before this (otherwise, you'll be sending messages to nil).  Also, I assume by `addedObject` above, you mean `selectedImage`.  One thing that jumps out at me is that

```
[layerBack display];
```

should be replaced with

```
[layerBack setNeedsDisplay];
```

From the [CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/display), in regards to `-display:`

> You should not call this method
>   directly.

There's more on setting the content of layers like this in the ["Providing Layer Content"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006642) section of the Core Animation Programming Guide.

Comment: David Duncan answered this on cocoa-dev maillist:

By default this will obliterate the contents that you have just set.
Calling -setNeedsDisplay or -display will cause the layer to generate content and set the contents property to the result of that operation. If you set the contents property manually, you should never call -setNeedsDisplay or -display on that layer or the content you set will be lost. You can avoid this by implementing some delegate methods or subclassing a CALayer, but it is generally easier to avoid the issue entirely by maintaining control over the CALayer when doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all I think you have to cast the CGImage to an id.

```
layerBack.contents = (id)selectedImage.CGImage;
```

And secondly, I think you have to add the layer to the views content layer

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layerBack];
```

But I have always made use of my custom UIViews class's + (Class)layerClass; to generate custom layers which layout their own sublayers, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Thanks. I did both changes and the layer is still not showing. If I may ask, can you, by any chance, kindly send me this class you've created? If you can, please mail it to "utugau-->at<--gmail"... All my hair is turning gray in despair with quartz...

Comment: I have added your suggestions to the original post because I have tested with them and the code is still not showing any content.

Answer (score 2):

Bridge it:

```
layerBack.contents = (__bridge id)selectedImage.CGImage;
```

Comment: The `(__bridge id)` is used in Cocoa's rather new ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) to transfer objects between Cocoa and Core foundation (or generally: C), for more see either the official documentation at Apple or [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) blog post by Mike Ash.

Answer (score 1):

What is selectedImage and how does it relate to addedObject?  From what I see, you get an image, but then add in an entirely different, unrelated image, possibly a blank one, to the layer.

Are you paying attention to messages Xcode is providing you?

Comment: that addObject was a typo when I copied the code to SO... as I changed a few variables when typing the code here to clarify...thanks for the help.